# Putting an icon at top-right corner of a button using css

Tags: css, image, icons

How do you put an image icon at the top  right corner of a button using css's `:before` and/or `after`?

Comment: Do you have any code to share? If you could narrow down your question that would be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

`:before` and `:after` will, by default, have their static positions based on element they're attached to.

Check out this snippet. By default, adding content to `:after` will display some text `inline` with the word Button.

Setting `:after` to `display: block` treats it as a block instead, so it falls below. I've added an image to the background of this new element.

Now if we set it's position to `absolute`, and move it to the top right, it shoots way off to the body's top right, because we don't have the button positioned relatively to anchor our `absolute` element.

The last button is set to `position: relative;` so the `:after` (which is absolutely positioned) will anchor to it, since `:before` and `:after` treat the element they're attached to as the parent.

```css
button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button.text:after {
    content: "After";
}

button.img:after {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='15' height='15'><circle cx='7.5' cy='7.5' r='5' /></svg>");
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
}

button.top-right:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

button.relative {
  position: relative;
}

button.cropper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

button.cropper:after {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40'><circle cx='20' cy='20' r='15' /></svg>");
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="text">Button</button>
<button class="img">Button</button>

<button class="img top-right">Button</button>

<button class="img top-right relative">Button</button>

<button class="img top-right relative cropper">Button</button>
```

Comment: Is there any way to  make the icon a bit off the top of the button? Like maybe half of the icon is within the scope of the button, and the half of the icon is outside the button?

Comment: Of course there is. I added another button type to my answer. Just position the `:after` outside of the button (such as setting a negative value) and make sure the button's overflow style is set to `overflow: hidden` - so anything that falls outside of the button will be clipped.

Comment: The [CSS Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics) doc and [Psuedo-Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) doc may be of use to you